# C# Compiler Switches in Release Mode

Tags: c#

I have an application where I used compiler switches to control whether large chunks of code were included or not. Think car with automatic transmission or manual transmission.
Works fine in Debug mode but in Release mode it looks like both Auto Transmission and Manual Transmission are compiled so the car doesn't drive too well...

So am I wrong in trying to get option control functionality out of compiler switches?

More Detail:
My understanding of compiler switches was flawed.

Simple project in comments below.(Not too good at driving StackOverFlow)

To continue the analogy, The (Winform) project was built with manual transmission. It was deployed in debug mode using a setup project. (Mistake).

After some years Auto-transmission was required. (No commonality to give rise to a base class).
The thought was that one day manual transmission may be required again)

Seemed like a compiler switch was a good idea to decide which block of code to use.
Again the Auto-transmission  version was deployed in debug mode.

After some more years of running I decided that it should be released. That was when I noticed the problem.

The simple example asked for (thanks) showed me that it wasn't both blocks that were being compiled, just the block in the #else. i.e. Release build regards the switch as off.

So unless I am missing something the answer is self-evident. Don't use compiler switches for deployment options.

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you are talking about - can you post some short code examples illustrating this?

Comment: Erm, so you basically lost track of the #ifdefs?  Then you are using too much of it.

Comment: Simple example shows that compiler switch is ignored in release build. I had it wrong in my original post. so unless I misunderstand. don't use compiler switches for project options.    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Display();
        }

 private void Display()
        {
 #if (MySwitch)          
             
             
             MessageBox.Show("MySwitch on");
#else

            MessageBox.Show("MySwitch off");
#endif
        }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use composition instead and make use of object-orientation.  Have two classes, one for `AutoTransmission`, and another for `ManualTransmission`.  Each one will derive from a base class `Transmission`  Then you can use either one as you see fit when you create the object that makes use of one of these transmissions.

Then, when you create the object that uses a `Transmission`, simply instantiate whatever transmission you need.  That could be defined in config, or it could be compiler constants.  But, I'd recommend against compiler constants because when you perform automatic refactorings blocks of could disabled by `#ifdef` will not be processed and may not build when you change your compiler options.